# ID this 90's stop motion film about little people

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a sci-fi/fantasy movie probably from the 90's, and I believe it was a stop motion film.

Little people from outer space are trying to find way back home guided by this small computer cube.

At the end of the film they manage to drive a truck using team work and ropes and get to a
space ship or something like that.

The title is probably the name of their kind.

Comment: It almost sounds like [The Borrowers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrowers_%281997_film%29) except for the computer cube and the space-theme

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Nome Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nome_Trilogy) by Terry Pratchett was made into a TV series, at least the first book, *Truckers*.

Thanks for this question, by the way. I didn't know that it was, so I only found out thanks to you!
And now, to find it...

Comment: I didn't either, but this was immediately what I thought of too.  I didn't realize it was that old...

Comment: It more recent years I've seen it referred to as the Bromeliad trilogy. Tony Robinson's readings of it are great.